Get specify type from Union Type with specify value
My code example here:
Typescript playground
In my code i have a function Post.getModel() that returns IUser and IPosts. How to make it return IPosts, because inside PostModel, I assigned "model" to "posts".

interface IUser {
  findMany(): any
}

interface IPosts {
  findMany(): any
}

type modelName = "users" | "posts"

const models: {
  users: IUser,
  posts: IPosts
} = {
  users: {
    findMany: () => []
  },
  posts: {
    findMany: () => []
  }
}

export abstract class ModelKernel {
  static model: modelName

  static getModel() {
    return models[this.model]
  }
}

export class Post extends ModelKernel {
  static model: modelName = "posts"
}


//// controller

const user = Post.getModel() // It's return IUser and IPosts


Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself. Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. Until the code is included here as plaintext, the question risks being closed as needing debugging details.
